# JavaScript slideToggle

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my website there are "boxes" that open when you click on the song name, but I would like to make the one that is open to close when you click on another song name. So just one box would be open at the time. The code that invokes boxes to appear is just below. Does anyone know the solution how i could achieve that ? P.S with image it would be a lot more understandable but I am not allowed to add images.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var showOrHide = true;
function parodyti (a) {
$(function () {
$("#nauj-" + a).slideToggle('slow', function () {})
 })
};</script>
```

Comment: may I see the html also?

Comment: Maybe it is enough to understand if you would see the actual website

www.muzikosfanai.lt

Comment: Oh man sorry, I forgot that only mods can see new template we are working on. If it is not too much trouble you can login by clicking "Prisijungimas" and then the name "test" and pass "test" and scroll a bit down where you can choose "Išdėstymas" and there is theme set to "mvideos" so you should choose "wp7" and you would be there to see the javascript boxes.

Comment: @RokasSkeivys That actually *is* too much trouble if you want a lot of people looking at your problem!

Comment: I understand that, I really do, but I cannot add a picture to make it clear..

Answer (score 0):

You can the jquery concept to do it . Jquery provides you with the method .toggle() to work it out . An example code will be like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button>Toggle</button>
<p>Hello</p>
<p style="display: none">Good Bye</p>
<script>

$("button").click(function () {
$("p").toggle();
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This will toggle on button press between the two strings Good Bye and Hello .

Answer (score 0):

Use `.click(function()` to achieve your task.

Refer [Jquery toggling the element one at a time](http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/javascript-dhtml-ajax/threads/420083/jquery-toggle-on-1-elm-at-a-time#) link for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you : http://jsfiddle.net/fd46R/

Its just a sample for your reference.

```
 $(function(){
    $('ul.child').hide();
    $('ul.parent a.slide').click(function(){
    $('ul.child').slideUp('slow');
    $(this).next().find('a').show();
        if( $(this).next().is(':hidden') ) {
    $(this).next().slideDown('fast');
        }
    return false;
    });
    });​
```